# HTML Agility Pack - Replace div node

Tags: .net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to replace a `div` with another `div` and it doesn't seem to work.
Any suggestions?

I have a copy on fiddle if you want to try it:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/A5a6I0

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var html =
        @"<div id='div1'> hello </div>";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        Console.WriteLine("\n****Before child node replaced****\n");

        Console.WriteLine(htmlDoc.Text);        

        HtmlNode oldChild =  htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='div1']");

        HtmlNode newChild = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<h2> This is h2 new child heading</h2>");

        Console.WriteLine("Node Name: " + oldChild.Name);


        oldChild.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newChild, oldChild);

        Console.WriteLine("\n****After child node replaced****\n");

        Console.WriteLine(htmlDoc.Text);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problems and potential bugs with HTMLAgilityPack updating the text property.

I was able to get it to work by replacing `htmlDoc.Text` with `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml`.